# Difference of simulated annealing and random search for generating crossword puzzles?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, simulated-annealing

I heard that when one wants to write a program to make a crossword puzzle, he can use for example simulated annealing as in the thesis [*Crossword Construction using Constraint Satisfaction and Simulated Annealing*](https://comserv.cs.ut.ee/home/files/Thesis_tomozov.pdf?study=ATILoputoo&reference=C59DCE2177378FCBA13A04AE9EE6BFF32105541E)
 by Pavel Tomozov or random search as in http://raksy.dyndns.org/sqpack2.py. What is the difference of simulated annealing and random search?

Comment: They are two different algorithms. What kind of difference are you interested in?

Comment: I was wondering this one would work better for the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983929/proving-that-a-particular-matrix-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1 or do they work at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing